# NSShadow set() method in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nsshadow

In [Apple's documentation for NSShadow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSShadow_Class/) in UIKit, they state:

> An NSShadow object may be used in one of two ways. First, it may be set, like a color or a font, in which case its attributes are applied to all content drawn thereafter—or at least until another shadow is applied or a previous graphics state is restored.

But NSShadow does not appear to have a `set()` method, at least with UIKit. Am I missing something, or is this a mistake on Apple's part (possible due to being copied verbatim from [the AppKit Mac OS X NSShadow documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSShadow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSShadow/set))?

Is there any way to achieve the `set()` behaviour, or are NSAttributedStrings the only thing NSShadow is useful for in UIKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve the `set()` behaviour

Not with NSShadow. Keep in mind, though, that all UIKit drawing is just a convenience for using CoreGraphics directly, which is where all the real action is anyway. Thus, for drawing in general, call `CGContextSetShadow`.

Comment: For example code and further discussion, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_shadows Note in particular that transparency layers are useful for accumulating drawing to which a single unified shadow is to be applied.